# textarea in draggable div without jqueryui

Tags: jquery, textarea, draggable

I have a problem with a textarea in a draggable div, I can't use the mouse to edit the text, I have to use the arrows… how to deal with this?

```js
  $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

  $('div').on("drag", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('div').on("dragstart", function (event) {
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null); //moz
      dragged = event.target;
  });

  $('textarea').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  })
```

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div draggable="true">
    <textarea>Hello</textarea>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1oe43zdL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle the ability to drag based on the mouseenter and mouseleave events of the textarea.

```
$('textarea').on("mouseenter", function (e) {
      draggable = false;
      $(e.target).parent().attr('draggable', false);
      e.preventDefault();
});

$('textarea').on("mouseleave", function (e) {
      $(e.target).parent().attr('draggable', true);
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/1oe43zdL/6/)